# ¿Cómo recodificar de igual forma varias variables de un data.frame de manera eficiente en R?

Tags: r, dataframe

Supongamos el siguiente `data.frame`:

```
sexo<-(1,1,0,1,0) # 1: hombre; 0:mujer
# asignacion de los valores para ruido, olores, contaminacion (características de la vivienda y su entorno):
# 1: mucho; 2:algo; 3:nada
ruido<-c(1,3,3,1,2) # ruido molesto del exterior
olores<-c(2,2,3,3,1) # malos olores en la vivienda
contaminacion<-c(2,3,1,2,3) # contaminacion en el entorno de la vivienda
acceso_agua<- c(2,3,1,2,2) # la vivienda NO dispone de acceso a agua de calidad
fuma<-c(1,0,1,0,0) # 1:si; 0:no

datos_modelo<-cbind.data.frame(ruido,olores,contaminacion,acceso_agua)
```

**Se desea recodificar las variables `ruido`, `olores`, `contaminacion` y `acceso_agua`  de tal manera que que los valores 2 y 3 tomen al valor 0, es decir, convertir esas variables en binarias.**

Actualmente lo estoy haciendo de la siguiente manera:

```
attach(datos_modelo)
datos_modelo$ruido[ruido == 2 | ruido == 3] <- 0
datos_modelo$olores[olores == 2 | olores == 3] <- 0 
datos_modelo$acceso_agua[acceso_agua == 2 | acceso_agua == 3] <- 0
```

Sin embargo, este código es un ejemplo reproducible de mi problema, ya que en realidad **tengo 14 variables que quiero recodificar de la misma manera en un `data.frame` de más de 40 variables**. Las variables que deseo recodificar están todas juntas dentro del data.frame, así que es posible llamarlas todas juntas por sus índices, en este ejemplo: `datos_modelo[2:4]`

¿Cómo puedo hacer la recodificación de manera más eficiente?: Con menos líneas de código y no tan repetitivamente.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una forma bien sencilla, siempre que los valores sean números del tipo 1/0, es usar un poco de aritmética de matrices.

```
seleccion <- c(1,2,4)
datos_modelo[, seleccion] <- datos_modelo[, seleccion] * (datos_modelo[, seleccion] == 1)
datos_modelo

  ruido olores contaminacion acceso_agua
1     1      0             2           0
2     0      0             3           0
3     0      0             1           1
4     1      0             2           0
5     0      1             3           0
```

Básicamente vamos a dejar en 1 los valores que ya son 1, y en 0 todo lo demás, por lo que generamos un vector de lógicos, dónde `FALSE` son aquellos valores distintos  a 1, luego al multiplicar los valores originales con esta matriz, esos `FALSE` terminarán siendo los 0 que buscamos.

Comment: Otra forma de hacer la selección sería: `seleccion<-c("ruido","olores","contaminacion",acceso_agua")`.

Comment: ¿Hay alguna forma de tener el mismo `data.frame`en tipo numérico y en tipo factor a la vez indicándole a R de alguna manera que solicito los mismos datos pero en distinto tipo dependiendo de lo que necesite hacer? Cuando quiero llevar a cabo el análisis descriptivo, necesito las variables en tipo numérico; pero para hacer alguna estimacion con `glm()`necesito la mayoría de las variables en tipo factor, pues estas son categóricas. Así que lo que hago es crear un `data.frame` con todas las variables de tipo numérico y otro `data.frame` igual pero con las variables categóricas en tipo factor.

Comment: Una buena idea es definir una función personalizada que haga la conversión factor-numérico para esos datos y usarla cuando la necesitas. Una forma más complicada y quizás exagerada para este caso sería definir una clase y definir métodos.

Comment: Hola juan, de hecho la selección por nombres se mucho más clara. Con respecto a lo que preguntas, creo que como dice mpaladino, una función que haga la traducción sería mejor, aunque si tienes capacidad de memoria, todavía más simple es mantener dos versiones de cada columna

Comment: Como ya he dicho, estoy estimando un modelo con glm(). Creo que sería mejor idea agrupar los valores de las variables que deseo modificar (`seleccion<-c("ruido","olores","contaminacion",acceso_agua")`) de la siguiente manera: que tomen el valor 1 si hay un 1 o un 2; que tomen el valor 0 si hay un 3. ¿Cómo podría hacerlo de manera eficiente?